# Creating quiz in flash/actionscript with questions passed through flashvars

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am getting questions from the database (just text) and then passing them to flash via flash vars.  I want one question to be displayed then the user will answer (text) and click a button and then the next question will be displayed for them to answer and so on.

I am not hoping for overly specific advice but as I am very new to flash/actionscript am just looking for broad advice (or links ?) on how to approach this.  Can I do it all from one frame just using actionscript ?

EDIT: I think what I am really after (assuming I am not way off track) is if all the questions should be handled at once which I guess will require some kind of loop that listens for some buttonclick event to move to the next question ..... or be 'reloading' the flash movie and dealing with only 1 question at a time.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw your edit, here's how I would do it:

```
//class var
private var answerHolder:Sprite = new Sprite();

private function createAnswers( answerArray:Array ){
    if(answerHolder.parent){ //Makes sure we have a parent, so we don't get an ugly error.
        answerHolder.parent.removeChild(answerHolder); //removes answerholder, cleans out previous answers
    }
    answerHolder = new Sprite(); //new empty sprite
    addChild(answerHolder); //Adds the new empty sprite
    for (var i in answerArray){
        var newAnswer:Answer = new Answer(); //have a movieclip with linkage set to Answer
        newAnswer.txt.text = answerArray[i]; //Have a text field in Answer with the instance name of txt
        newAnswer.x = 50;
        newAnswer.y = 100 + newAnswer.width * i;
        newAnswer.name = i;
        addChild(newAnswer);
        newAnswer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, selectedChoice); //MAKE SURE to have imported MouseEvents!
    }
}
private function selectedChoice(e:MouseEvent) {
    trace('Selected ' + e.name);
}
```

This is no means completed code or anything (You will get an error because I didn't write a constructor, nor the questions, and I pulled answerArray out of thin air, you also need to addChild(answerHolder) too), it's something to get started :)

createAnswers() can be called again, when you have a new question - this is because the sprite that holds answerHolder is cleared.

Comment: Thankyou very much !

Yes I did not need a loop, just not used to eventlisteners I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this:

1. Create a PHP file that has a whatever-delimited list of all your questions outputted onto it, for example:
   What is the time?`#`Where do you live?`#`How much water do you drink per day?`#`How old are you?
2. Use [`URLLoader`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) to load a list of all your questions in Flash.
3. Create an Array containing all of your questions by using `split("#")` on the String that you've received from your PHP page via the `URLLoader`.

That should get you started.

Comment: Hi thank you very much.  But to clarify I think I can do this part. What I think I really wish to know is if I should either .... 

- pass all the questions and then do it in flash, which I guess would require some kind of loop and listening for some buttonclick event to move onto the next question OR

- somehow reload the flash and be only passing 1 question at a time and when the user clicks a button the page is reloaded with a new question in flashvars/URLloader 

At least I think these are very roughly my 2 options.  Thanks !

Comment: Reloading flash files will take up bandwidth and yoru sever power. I suggest 1. Also you just need a eventlistener, no loops needed, very easy